# "et al." for 3 or more authors, not 4 or more, authors in a citation call-out with "aea" bibliography style

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing, natbib

I'm using the AEA template with `natbib`. I want to have citations with 3 authors show "FirstAuthor et al." instead of all 3 authors' names. (The bibliography style uses the "et al." truncation automatically if a publication has *four or more* authors.)

I believe that a change needs to be made in the change_AEA.bst file in this section (but am unsure of what/how to change):

```
FUNCTION {format.names.label}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
  { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr "{ff }{vv~}{ll}{, jj}"  format.name$ 't := 
      nameptr #1 >
        { namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            { t "others" =
              { " et~al." * }
              { " \harvardand\ " * t * }
              if$
            }
            if$
        }
        't
        if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
    while$
}
```

I believe the original .bst file can be found here: https://www.aeaweb.org/journals/policies/templates

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. The journal will ignore any changes you make to the format. Don't bother.

Comment: Changes should still work for internal use though (which is what I need it for).

Answer (score 1):

Echoing the sentiment expressed by @Johannes_B, I don't think it's a good idea to modify the file `aea.bst`. In my opinion, the only valid reason for using this particular bibliography style is if you're planning to submit a paper either to the American Economic Review or to one of its sister publications.

However, if you really, absolutely, *must* change the cutoff threshold for using `et al` in citation call-outs, I suggest you proceed as follows:

- Make a copy of the file `aea.bst` and call the copy, say, `aeamod.bst`. (Don't modify the file `aea.bst` directly).
- Open the file `aeamod.bst` in a text editor. The editor you use for the your tex files is fine.
- In `aeamod.bst`, search for the BibTeX function called `format.names.label.short`. (It starts on line 572 in my copy of the file.)
- In this function, locate the line

  ```
    numnames #3 >
  ```

  Change it to

  ```
    numnames #2 >
  ```
- Save the file `aeamod.bst` either in the directory where your main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter option, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably.
- In your main tex file, change the instruction

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{aea}
  ```

  to

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{aeamod}
  ```

  and run a full recompile sequence -- LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more -- to propagate the effects of the change you made to the bibliography style file.

Happy BibTeXing!

---

A full MWE (minimum working example) and its output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{ab,author="Albertson, Angela and Bronson, Bronwyn",title="Thoughts",year=3000}
@misc{abc,author="Angela Albertson and Bronwyn Bronson and Cristina Christensen",title="Thoughts",year=3001}
@misc{abcd,author="Angela Albertson and Bronwyn Bronson and Cristina Christensen and Darla Drorsen", title="Thoughts",year=3001}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{har2nat}
\bibliographystyle{aeamod}

\begin{document}
\cite{ab}

\cite{abc}

\cite{abcd}

\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```